# How to enable NVidia GeForce 940M on Linux Deepin (Debian Unstable based)

Tags: linux, drivers, debian, graphics-card

I am very newbie to Linux and I have this Samsumg notebook that have both Intel HD Graphics 5500 and NVIDIA GeForce 940M GPUs on it, past week I decided to start using a distro called Deepin instead of my Windows 10, mostly because I wanted Docker to run natively and also wanted a good looking UI.

So I installed it and everything seems ok, I also updated it and installed some proprietary driver using Deepin Driver Manager:

[image]

Still, I noticed some lag when running some applications together and virtual desktops, also when I run an application called NVidia XServer Settings that is present on my system since I installed the driver as shown in the picture above, I see this weird message:

[image]

If I run the command shown there, I got an error:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
sudo: nvidia-xconfig: command not found
```

I did some research but can't conclude anything, and also I'm afraid of messing up my system since I've just spent a day setting up my development environment.

So I have basically 3 questions for you guys:

1. How do I know if my GeForce GPU is actually enabled?
2. If it is activated, how do I force my system to use it instead of the onboard one?
3. If it is not activated, installed or configured, how I managed to get it done?

Here are some other info that can be usefull:

```
uname -a
Linux marcoskichel-PC 4.9.0-deepin9-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT Deepin 4.9.29-4 (2017-07-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux


lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 30)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940M] (rev ff)
```

Comment: Any luck finding a solution? I'm having the same issue.